# Weighted mean in SAS

Tags: sas, mean, weighted

I have problem with some SAS code. Within first weighted mean grouping by "date", I want to compute again weighted mean using "group" with by option and "w2" as weight. How can I do this?

```
proc univariate data=set_out;
by date;
weight w1;
VAR price;
run;
```

Comment: Please show some example data and expected output for that data.  Just enough variables and observations to demonstrate the issue.  Post data as text, preferable as a SAS data step.

Answer (score 0):

The `weight` statement accepts only one variable, so you will need to use `UNIVARIATE` twice:

```
proc sort data=have;
  by date;
proc univariate data=have;
  by date;
  weight w1;
  VAR price;
  output out=want mean=mean_price;
run;
```

and

```
proc sort data=have;
  by group;
proc univariate data=have;
  by group;
  weight w2;
  VAR price;
  output out=want mean=mean_price;
run;
```

If you don't want to sort the data use a `CLASS` statement instead of `BY`